# Regular Expression in @Path for RESTEasy Web Method

Tags: java, regex, rest, resteasy

I need to add a regular expression to my `@Path` statement for my RESTEasy web method to allow the two following types of urls below to connect to the web method:

- http://mydomain.com/Things/r2lXIcBfNfnp2yOK.1
- http://mydomain.com/Things/r2lXIcBfNfnp2yOK.1.0.0

... where the id = 'r2lXIcBfNfnp2yOK', and the version can be either '1' or '1.0.0'.  How can I do this?

My method so far, which accepts version as '1.0.0' but not '1':

```
 @GET() 
 @Produces("application/x-protobuf") 
 @Path("/Things/{id}.{version:
 (([0-9\\*]+\\.[0-9\\*]+\\.[0-9\\*]+))}")
    public String getThing( 
       @PathParam("id") String id, 
    @PathParam("version") @DefaultValue("1.0.0") String version, 
    @Context final HttpServletResponse response) 
{       
       //.... (rest of the method, irrelevant
}
```

What is another regular expression that I can add to the @Path statement above to also allow '1' as a version?

I've tried this:

```
@Path("/{id}.{version: (([0-9\\*^\\.])|([0-9\\*]+\\.[0-9\\*]+\\.[0-9\\*]+))}
```

... but that doesn't work.

I've also tried this:

```
@Path("/{id}.{version: (([0-9\\*])|([0-9\\*]+\\.[0-9\\*]+\\.[0-9\\*]+))}
```

... but that just cuts off the first digit when I pass in a version '1.0.0' so that it becomes '0.0'.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: this is the only two allowed ?

Comment: Yes, <number>.<number>.<number>  or just <number> for version only.

Comment: try this: (([0-9]*+\.){2}+([0-9]{1}))|([0-9]{1})

Comment: The idea of using the number of numerics in curly braces {} was right, but for the format I used in @Path, the non-alphanumeric characters need to be escaped by '\\', not '\'.  A minor thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\\d+((\\.\\d+){2})?` for allowing either `<number>` or `<number>.<number>.<number>`

`\\d+` allows one or more digits

`(\\.\\d+){2}` allows pattern of **a . followed by one or more digits** occurring **twice**

the following `?` makes the second pattern optional